# Атрибут required для Select (то работает, то нет)

Tags: html

Почему одно работает, а второе нет?

С идентичными кодом!

```html
<form>
  Пример 1 (не работает)
<fieldset>

<legend>Кто косил траву на поляне?</legend>
   <select required size='1' name='project_type' style='width: 308px; color: #333333; border: solid 1px #000000; border-radius:4px; box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 4px 0px #bbbbbb; background-color:#f0f0f0; padding-bottom:2px; font:bold 14px "Trebuchet MS";'>
    
    <option value='1'>Косари</option>
    <option value='2'>Кесари</option>
    <option value='3'>Караси</option>
    <option value='4'>Зайцы</option>
    <option value='5'>Волки</option>
    <option value='6'>Бараны</option>
    <option value='other'>затрудняюсь с ответом</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</fieldset>
</form>

<hr>Пример 2 (работает)
<form>
  <p>Какое растение в списке вечнозелёное?</p>
  <p>
    <select name="pregunta" required>
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Ольха</option>
      <option value="2">Берёза</option>
      <option value="3">Бузина</option>
      <option value="4">Тис</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </p>
</form>
```

[Ссылка на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrffyrzb/5/) (в нём конкретно видно это срабатывание\несрабатывание).

Почему первый пример разрешает, когда пользователь ничего не выбирает?

Comment: а какой смысл в selected если нельзя выбрать вариант ответа?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разобрался! Надо чтобы `value` было пустым.

```
<option selected disabled value=''>Ответьте правильно на вопрос:</option>
```

Comment: Ой, я почти отправил такой ответ, но вы чуть быстрее меня)

Comment: #Peter Olson Спасибо. Просто может кому и сгодится.

Comment: @I_CaR ну ты крутой, сильно помог, спасибо.

Comment: Select required теперь работает в Chrome!
================================================== Вот мой случай: `<select id="sobr" name="sobr" required> <option disabled="" selected="" value=''>выберите тип собрания</option> <option value="внеочередного" >внеочередного</option> <option value="годового">годового</option> </select>` Без `value=''` работало в Mozilla, в Chrome нет. Когда добавил value='' в Chrome тоже заработало! Спасибо I_CaR!